# Which method to resize UIImage is better and why?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, graphics, core-graphics

To all of you graphics experts, I was wondering which one of these two methods is better for resizing a UIImage:

The first one I've come across is simple and popular and is the following:

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(CGFloat)resizedWidth height:(CGFloat)resizedHeight
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(resizedWidth ,resizedHeight));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight)];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

The second method I found at this link http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/06/Resize-image-and-keep-aspect-ratio.aspx and seems to accomplish the same as the above, but is much more intricate (I don't really understand what is going on in it):

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(CGFloat)resizedWidth height:(CGFloat)resizedHeight
 {
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, resizedWidth, resizedHeight, 8, 4 * resizedWidth, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;  
}
```

So my question is, which way is better and why?

Answer (score 4):

The second one is thread safe.

Comment: Why is this woted down? 1: Becasue the statement is wrong? 2: Because threading is irellevant -> it's not. If you want a high performance app, putting resizing tasks into another thread is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather late reply, but I'll just go ahead and add it anyways.

I actually found some behavioral differences between the two methods, besides prestanda.

In an photo app of mine, I have custom camera view that sends any taken image to a custom image editor. In the app, the custom camera/editor views are landscape exclusive. However, the native camera window itself it NOT.

So, whenever a photo happened to be taken in portrait mode, the end result is distorted. These distortions are easily handled by flipping the width and height, whenever width < height.

The first method of the two above methods (the simple one) resulted in an image that was rotated 90 degrees and still distorted. The second, however, resized the image perfectly!

I guess that this has something to do with the graphics context-based behavior. The second method does not use this context, and it works flawlessly in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It's a high-level and a low-level approach.

Which is better? Depends on your goal.

The high-level approach is more readable (for me), maybe the low-level approach is a nanosecond faster (didn't test that).

It's hard to judge algorithms ...

Comment: Low level approach = maintain the quality better after the resize? @tom

Answer (score 0):

There are really different ways that you may want to resize an image. Even if the case where you have a new width and a new height, you may either want to resize the image to a new size and ignore proportions, or to scale image proportionally and crop to a new size.

There's a project that has a clean API for doing that: https://github.com/mustangostang/UIImage-Resize. It uses the first approach :-)